# How do I compare Dict literal with a constructed Dict?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to test an algorithm that builds up a HashDict, but I can't get my "expected" to *actually* equal my "actual." For example,

```
iex> expected = HashDict.new([ key: 12 ])
#HashDict<[foo: 12]>

iex> actual = Dict.put(HashDict.new, "key", 12)
#HashDict<[{"foo", 12}]>
```

I can get the second "style" of `HashDict` in a literal by declaring it in a much more obtuse way:

```
iex> HashDict.new([ { "key", 12 } ])
#HashDict<[{"foo", 12}]>
```

I really like the simple Dict literal syntax for my test case, but my implementation builds up the Dict recursively. How can I make these equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case the key is an atom, but in the second case it is a string.

You can do this on iex:

```
expected = HashDict.new([key: 12])
actual = Dict.put(HashDict.new, :key, 12)
Dict.equals? actual, expected # returns true
```

For more information visit: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/

Comment: This definitely works. Thanks. Sadly, it means my test cases don't produce very informative error messages.

Comment: `"key"` is not the same as `:key`. There's no way to make those equal. You can convert one to the other so they are the same though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question (HashDict has been deprecated for quite a few Elixir releases at this point), but I thought I'd update it for current Elixir releases in case anyone else finds it in the future.

Instead of HashDict, you should be using [Map](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) these days.

The Map literal syntax can support strings as keys like this:

```
%{"foo" => 12}
```

This is, of course, different from using an atom key in a Map literal, which is idiomatically declared like this:

```
%{foo: 12}
```

That's just syntactic sugar around declaring it like this:

```
%{ :foo => 12 }
```